# ReactJs: invalidateQueries not working after useMutation

Tags: reactjs, caching

I am trying to learn `react.js` with `@tanstack/react-query` and so far things are working fine.

However, I am trying to use `invalidateQueries` to clear the existing cache after `insert`, `update`, etc. to fetch the fresh data from the server. But, its not working.

I have already tried various solutions found after googling, but still not success.

main.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
...

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
            staleTime: 10 * (60 * 1000), // 10 mins
            refetchOnMount: false,
        },
    },
});

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            ...
        </QueryClientProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

edit.tsx

```js
const update = async (data: any) => {
    ...
};

export default () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    ...

    const { mutate, isLoading } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: update,
        onError: ({ response }) => setErrors(showErrors(response.data)),
        onSuccess: () => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries([modules.accountTypes.cacheKey]);

            navigate(PATH);
        },
    });

    ...
};
```

Comment: could you share the query you wrote for fetching/mutating data with key `modules.accountTypes.cacheKey`

Comment: `modules.accountTypes.cacheKey` = 'accountTypes'

Comment: are you sure that you used the same key for the query also?

Comment: Absolutely, already verified several times

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code using `@tanstack/react-query v5` and It worked. Here is the code I tested:

Query

```
function MyQuery() {
  const { isLoading, isError, error, data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["accountTypes"],
    queryFn: () =>
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=5").then(
        (res) => {
          console.log('Query is called.');
          return res.json();
        }
      ),
  });

...
```

Mutation

```
function MyMutation() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { isPending, isError, error, data, mutate } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: () =>
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_limit=5").then(
        (res) => res.json()
      ),
    onError: ({ response }) => setErrors(showErrors(response.data)),
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["accountTypes"] });
      navigate("/my-path");
    },
  });

...
```

You can also try making `onSuccess` an `async` function, put `await` before `queryClient.invalidateQueries` and see what happens.

Comment: My react-query version is 4, let me try on 5.

Comment: If you want to stick to the v4, Adding return before the invalidate function may also help. Saw this as a solution in another question.

Comment: Ok, could you please post the link of that question..? So I can have a look.

Comment: Here you are: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75415014/react-query-usequery-not-refetching-after-usemutation?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you @Amirreza. I looked at the posted link and though, adding `return` may provide the solution, it will also prevents the redirection code from executing, written after. Therefore, I chose to upgraded from v4 to v5 and it worked. Many thanks again..:)

Comment: Alternatively, the `removeQueries` in place of `invalidateQueries` can be used. I am using this in v5 as `invalidateQueries` was still troubling me. The `removeQueries` is working flawlessly.

Comment: I think ```removeQueries``` also clears the cache.